# tf re-boadcaster

Tags: ros, transform-broadcaster, robot-state-publisher, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like a way to publish tf transforms, but using a standard ros::Publisher instead of the tf::TransformBroadcaster.  (I won't go into the reasons why).

The only way I think this can be done is to publish stamped transforms on a designated topic, then having a second node which subscribes to this topic and simply re-publishes them with the transform broadcaster.

Any other ideas?  Is there a standard node that does this already?  (I know about the robot_state_publisher which almost fits my needs).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12938/tf-re-boadcaster/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2012-02-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure I'm entirely clear on your use case.  I've commented on @Pablo Iñigo Blasco answer that you can easily implement the tf protocol.  It's just publishing a tf/TFMessage on the /tf topic.

You can publish it yourself on a topic of your choice, and populate the message yourself using a standard ros::Publisher just as done inside the TransformBroadcaster does internally.  [See the source code, ~ 30 lines](https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry/file/124b83ef922a/tf/src/transform_broadcaster.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on 2012-02-09**:
Thanks for the pointer to the code.  That is kind of what i expected to see after i did some initial testing.  Simply publishing to /tf won't work for me because i will have multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You said that you wanted to use ros::Publisher to send tf messages. That's of course possible.

It is not clear what you want to do. In any case it sounds like the tf_remap node could be useful for you. If the first node publishes on a topic ie: /my_tf then the tf_remap node could republish each message of this topic to the /tf topic.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2012-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-08**:
There's nothing especially fancy inside the tf::TransformBroadcaster, it's only ~30 lines .  Source here: https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry/file/124b83ef922a/tf/src/transform_broadcaster.cpp  The tf_prefix stuff is deprecated and you could ignore it.  And the rest is just helper accessors.

**Comment by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on 2012-02-08**:
Your post makes me think, what is the difference between using the tf::TransformBroadcaster and publishing to the /tf topic?